# What mean Cholek, Chozer, modey and Gozer?

Tags: words, hebrew, talmud-gemara

When studying Massechet Ketubot with a Rabbi, he often says "He is Cholek", "He is Chozer", "He is Modey" or "He is Gozer". These four words seem related. It seems, according to the context, that they have something to do with the Kiddushin Al Tnay (Kiddushin made with a condition). Can you please tell me what these words mean? I searched them in the Melamed Dictionary with no success.

Comment: Czolek pronounced cholek is also a Jewish family name.

Comment: Seems off-topic as Hebrew language rather than Judaism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cholek comes from the same word as machloket. "He is cholek" means "he argues".

Chozer means to retract, so "he is chozer" means "he retracts [his opinion]".

Modeh means, in this context, to agree. "He is modeh": he agrees.

Gozer is similar to gezera. A gezera is a decree meant to prevent people from coming close to a sin. So, "he is gozer" means "he makes a gezera (decree)".

Comment: +1 perhaps modeh is better translated in context to mean admit.